# Problema en VueJS - Contenteditable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs

Tengo un problema cuando mediante un listado de objetos creo componentes en pantalla. En realidad el problema surge cuando elimino un item del listado

muestro un ejemplo del problema, tengo un listado con 2 items
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al presionar el boton eliminar en donde dice "quien" me sucede que la pantalla queda asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya no se que hacer, el array queda bien pero el div editable queda mal con el dato que se borro.

Aqui paso el codigo

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div 
            v-for="(encoding, index) in form.encodings" 
            :key="`encoding-${index}`" 
        >
            <h1>{{ encoding.encodingString }}</h1>
            <div contenteditable="true" 
                class="tarea"
                :value="encoding.text" 
                @input="emitText(index, $event)"
            >
            </div>
            <button @click="form.encodings.splice(index, 1)">
                Eliminar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</template>
<script>

export default {
    data : function(){
        return {
            form : {
                encodings : [
                    { encodingString : 'quien', text : null},
                    { encodingString : 'como paso', text : null }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    methods : {
        emitText : function(index, evt){
            this.form.encodings[index].text = evt.target.innerText
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
    div.tarea {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
    background-color: white;
    font: small courier, monospace black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

No es buena idea utilizar el indice que te da el `v-for` para definir la `key`. `key` es utilizada por vue para reactividad, y se basa en la misma para volver a renderizar el template o no.

La solución mas sencilla seria utilizar la propia propiedad de `encoding.encodingString` en su lugar, o si se va a repetir, utilizar un parametro tipo `id`

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#el',
  data : function(){
    return {
      form : {
        encodings : [
          { encodingString : 'quien', text : null},
          { encodingString : 'como paso', text : null }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods : {
    emitText : function(index, evt){
      this.form.encodings[index].text = evt.target.innerText
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div.tarea {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  font: small courier, monospace black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; 
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <div 
       v-for="(encoding, index) in form.encodings" 
       :key="`encoding-${encoding.encodingString}`" 
       >
    <h1>{{ encoding.encodingString }}</h1>
    <div contenteditable="true" 
         class="tarea"
         :value="encoding.text" 
         @input="emitText(index, $event)"
         >
    </div>
    <button @click="form.encodings.splice(index, 1)">
      Eliminar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial!!, eso soluciono mi problema, ahora mismo lo aplico, muchisimas gracias!!!